# When Log Shows Inactivity for More Than 5 minutes

Tags: powershell

This PowerShell snippet works as expected, but I need to add functionality which detects when then file is inactive for more than 5 minutes.  How would you suggest this can be done, please?  When this condition is met - I have a notification function that I'll call when this event is triggered.  Just need to now how to trap this occurrence.

```
$File = "server.log"
$Path = "D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs"
$result = Get-ChildItem $Path -recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $File } 
Get-Content $result.FullName -Tail 1 -Wait|Select-string -Pattern "myapp"|foreach {
    "Another line was added: " + $_
}
```

Comment: Easy. Include a check  in your `Where-Object` if the `LastWriteTime` is more than 5 minutes ago.

Comment: the only problem with using LastWriteTime is the log file is being written to, but the timestamp remains on created time.  this is why  I'm writing this PowerShell - because the time stamp doesn't update with writes to the file.

Comment: That sounds pretty unlikely. Did you double check this?

Comment: Try to store the current file size in a variable and check if actual file size is still the same after 5 minutes.

Comment: If your file is on a NTFS drive check the setting for: HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem  The Key value or NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate.  If set to 1 the system will not update the Last Accessed Date. Set to zero to enable updating of Last Accessed Date.

Comment: @RetiredGeek Last Accessed Date also changes when someone only reads a file, so I don't think it is suitable for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use a FilesystemWatcher to monitor changes to the file:

```
# Create a new FileSystemWatcher object
# to monitor the folder holding the target file
$FileWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -ArgumentList 'D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs'

# Get the starting datetime
# so we can calculate the time between file changes
$global:previous = Get-Date

# Maximum time in minutes between changes
# Warn the user, if this is exceeeded
$timeout = 5

# Action to take after each file change
$Action = {
    $eventTime = $Event.TimeGenerated
    $fullPath  = $Event.SourceArgs[1].FullPath
    $fileName  = $Event.SourceArgs[1].Name

    # We're only interested in the server log
    if($fileName -eq 'Server.Log') {
        # How long since the last change?
        $elapsed = [Math]::Round(([DateTime]$eventTime - $global:previous).TotalMinutes, 2)

        # Note the current time for comparison with the next change
        $global:previous = Get-Date

        # Get the last thing written to the log
        $newText = Get-Content -Tail 1 -Path $fullPath

        # Tell the user
        Write-Host "[$eventTime][$elapsed] -- $newText"
    }
}

# Register for change events
$eventParams = @{
    InputObject      = $FileWatcher
    EventName        = 'changed'
    SourceIdentifier = 'Filesystemwatcher.changed'
    Action           = $Action
}
Register-ObjectEvent @eventParams | Out-Null

# Loop forever, cheking the elapsed time
while($true) {
    $eventTime = Get-Date

    $elapsed = [Math]::Round(($eventTime - $global:previous).TotalMinutes, 2)

    # Warn the user
    if($elapsed -ge $timeout){
        Write-Host "[$eventTime][$elapsed] -- WARNING: Timeout exceeded!"
        
        $global:previous = $eventTime
    }

    # Wait a second before we check again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

# If the timeout is not required
# Remove/comment-out the 'while' block above
# and uncomment 'Wait-Event' below
#Wait-Event
```

This produces output similar to this:

```
[07/01/2022 08:47:18][0.6] -- Log entry 1
[07/01/2022 08:51:41][4.37] -- Log entry 2
[07/01/2022 08:56:42][5.01] -- WARNING: Timeout exceeded!
[07/01/2022 08:59:40][2.95] -- Log entry 3
[07/01/2022 09:00:33][0.89] -- Log entry 4
```

Some things to note:

- My example simply logs the events, but you can, obviously, do other things instead.  For example, send an email if the log is idle too long.
- I tested this under very light load.  I'm not sure how it will handle the scenario where the log is being hammered with updates.  Give it a go and see.
- The event subscription is removed once your PowerShell session ends.  If you want to keep using the sessions and remove it manually, use this: `Get-EventSubscriber Filesystemwatcher.changed | Unregister-Event`