# Get-ChildItem (gci) and watch or wait for changes

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, powershell-7.2

There are occasions when I need to investigate an issue with a user while I watch the log messages in real-time.

I have a bunch of Powershell scripts for grabbing the log files that I need based on the criteria I'm looking for. Most often, it's a fairly simple [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) (`gci`) with an `Include` and `Select-String` such as the below:

```
gci -Recurse -Include *20220809*.jso" | Select-String "Bobby Davro"
```

However, once it's found all the results, it stops. What I'm looking for is a reactive script which can run and keep running until something happens.

**Is there a way to set a 'watch' or 'wait' on Get-ChildItem in Powershell 7.2?**

If not, is there another way to achieve this?

What I'm after is similar to `Get-Content x.log -Wait -Tail 100` which gets the last 100 lines of the file 'x.log' and then continues to wait for any new results. However, that's only looking at one file, whereas there could potentially be hundreds in my searches - hence using gci.

Am I doing something in my script that I could do better/differently in order to make it faster, safer, more efficient, etc?

**Edit:**

There have been some excellent comments regarding the user of [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher). Unfortunately, I was hoping for a smaller, more compact script as I don't always have permissions to install modules.

Many of the implementations of `FileSystemWatcher` don't lend themselves to portability or ease-of-use unless they're installed as modules which means I have to pretty much rule this out.

I have also looked at [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) as an alternative but this cannot scan for changes in real-time. I think changes in 1 minute increments - `/MOT:1` - are the best I could hope for there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [FileSystemWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+FileSystemWatcher)

Comment: Check out my previous answer for an example of using a FilesystemWatcher to monitor files/folders: [When Log Shows Inactivity for More Than 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808319/when-log-shows-inactivity-for-more-than-5-minutes/72826529#72826529)

Comment: @zett42 Thank you. I have previously looked at FileSystemWatcher and robocopy as potential solutions, but the former requires a significant amount of code to work properly (at least in all examples I've seen), and the latter doesn't run any faster than once a minute when monitoring for changes.

Comment: You could try a PowerShell wrapper like [this one](https://github.com/wgross/fswatcher-engine-event).

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. I was hoping there would be something much smaller and more succinct. I can't install modules on many of the servers so I am restricted in most cases to an inline script block.